# Counting number of instances of variant across multiple variants in a case control cohort using R

Tags: r, loops, bioinformatics

I have a table of genetic variants with each row representing a patient in whom the variant is seen and whether that variant is seen in a case or a control. I would like to output a separate matrix with three columns - variant, number in cases and number in controls in order to perform a Fisher's test.

I am using R and the table looks like this (PID - patient ID)

```
Variant ID      PID     Disease
2:4324:2343     FF354   Yes
2:4324:2343     FF355   Control
2:4324:2343     FF356   Control
2:4324:2343     FF357   Yes
2:4324:2343     FF358   Yes
3:346543:345    FF354   Yes
3:346543:345    FF358   Control
3:346543:345    FF390   Control
3:346543:345    FF391   Yes
6:234:34234     FF358   Yes
6:234:34234     FF390   Control
6:234:34234     FF358   Control
6:234:34234     FF213   Yes
```

The desired output would be:

```
Variant ID  Disease Control
2:4324:2343     3   2
3:346543:345    2   2
6:234:34234     2   2
```

I think I would have to use a loop in R but I must admit this is beyond me at present whilst I get to grips with R. Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `tapply` which gives you a nice matrix.

```
with(dat, tapply(Disease, list(Variant_ID, Disease), length))
#              Control Yes
# 2:4324:2343        2   3
# 3:346543:345       2   2
# 6:234:34234        2   2
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Variant_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2:4324:2343", "3:346543:345", 
"6:234:34234"), class = "factor"), PID = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("FF213", 
"FF354", "FF355", "FF356", "FF357", "FF358", "FF390", "FF391"
), class = "factor"), Disease = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: Thanks worked really well! In reality the table is thousands of rows long and therefore some of the entries for "yes" or "control" come up NA (which I can change to zero very easily). Going through this what does the "with" function add?

Comment: `with` points to your data frame, it's similar to `tapply(dat$Disease, list(dat$Variant_ID, dat$Disease), length)`, you know. Very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

We can get the frequency `count` and then reshape it to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    count(VariantID, Disease) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Disease, values_from = n)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  VariantID    Control   Yes
#  <chr>          <int> <int>
#1 2:4324:2343        2     3
#2 3:346543:345       2     2
#3 6:234:34234        2     2
```

---

Or with `table` from `base R`

```
table(df1[c('VariantID', 'Disease')])
#            Disease
#VariantID      Control Yes
# 2:4324:2343        2   3
# 3:346543:345       2   2
# 6:234:34234        2   2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(VariantID = c("2:4324:2343", "2:4324:2343", "2:4324:2343", 
"2:4324:2343", "2:4324:2343", "3:346543:345", "3:346543:345", 
"3:346543:345", "3:346543:345", "6:234:34234", "6:234:34234", 
"6:234:34234", "6:234:34234"), PID = c("FF354", "FF355", "FF356", 
"FF357", "FF358", "FF354", "FF358", "FF390", "FF391", "FF358", 
"FF390", "FF358", "FF213"), Disease = c("Yes", "Control", "Control", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Control", "Control", "Yes", "Yes", "Control", 
"Control", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L
))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer in your first script I get "cannot find the function pivot_wider" despite loading in the libraries specificed. In the second script I get the following erroer :When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified 
  either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as
  sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data 
  due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: To clarify my columns actually don't have headers (I did that to make the example clearer so substituted 'VariantID' and 'disease' for df$V1 and df$V9 respectively). I would really love a base R method to work as I work within a HPC where getting anything non base in or out is tricky. Thanks again.

Comment: @tacrolimus Please check your `tidyr` version `packageVersion('tidyr')` the function is available from `1.0.0` version.  Second is just a `table` function from `base R`.  If you check my `data`, it is just a `data.frame` and not a `data.table`.  If you had a `data.table`, then subsetting could be the issue `table(df1[, .(VariantID, Disease)])`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dcast` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df); dcast(df, VariantID ~ Disease)

#     VariantID  Control  Yes
#1  2:4324:2343       2   3
#2  3:346543:345      2   2
#3  6:234:34234       2   2
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(VariantID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2:4324:2343", "3:346543:345", "6:234:34234"), class = "factor"), PID = structure(c(2L, 3L,4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("FF213","FF354", "FF355", "FF356", "FF357", "FF358", "FF390", "FF391"), class = "factor"), Disease = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer. Worked really well and gives zero's instead of N/As which is great. To understand, dcast reshapes the table conflating the two columns you have given it (with the ~ symbol)?